# Zend CLI not working

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

My app is working from the web side of things.

I'd like to get the CLI working so that I can run unit tests and the such

Here's what I have for a test script:

```
$pthRoot = dirname(__FILE__);
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..'));
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'development');
define('SERVER_ROLE', 'development');

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library') . PATH_SEPARATOR . realpath($pthRoot . '/../controllers')  
     . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path()  
)));
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto'); 

require_once('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');  
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

require '../bootstrap.php';

require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$_SERVER['SERVER_ROLE'] = 'development';
$bootstrap = $application->getBootstrap();
$bootstrap->runScript();

$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
$sql = "select * from settings";
print_r($db->fetchAll($sql));
```

Unfortunately, I get an error at the get('db') line.

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'The mysql driver is not currently installed'

According to phpinfo from the command line, the mysql driver is running.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a MySQL Adapter with Zend Framework, you have two possibilities (I quote [the doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html#zend.db.adapter)) :

- MySQL, using the **pdo_mysql** PHP extension
- MySQL, using the **mysqli** PHP extension

Which one of those are you trying to use ?

If it's the first one, is the extension pdo_mysql activated for CLI ?
(you can use "php -m" to get the list of extensions that are loaded)

If it's the second one, is the extension mysqli activated for CLI ?

It seems none of the two adapter are using the extension *mysql* (which is quite old) ; so, if this one appears, it's probably not really relevant.

With a bit of luck, it'll just be that "the right extension" is loaded in the php.ini file used for Web, and not in the one used for CLI...

Comment: It's using pdo_mysql.  What I don't get is that I'm using the same config file for both situations, so shouldn't it be the same extensions that get loaded?

Comment: Oh, I see the difference. It's the additional ini files scanned.  Never encountered this before - the cli php isn't scanning the directory for extra ini files.  I added those .so's to my php.ini and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the `pdo_mysql.so` extention of Zend Server to you `php-cli` extension folder and the `pdo_mysql.ini` file of Zend Server to the ini folder of `php-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

When running Zend Server, you have to source `/etc/zce.rc` to get the php cli working, if the command is not in your profile:

`$ . /etc/zce.rc`

Answer (score 0):

To get PHP CLI working on Zend Server try this from https://serverfault.com/questions/356775/how-to-install-php-cli-with-pnctl-alongside-zend-server

Extend your $PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/zend/bin:/usr/local/zend/sbin
```

Or more permanently:

```
cat >> $HOME/.bashrc <<EOF
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/zend/bin:/usr/local/zend/sbin
EOF
reboot
```